# IS there a way to open a power bi file from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, windows, button, powerbi

So here is the problem, I want to create a buttun onExcel that leads to a Power BI file and I have no clue of how to do it, i also looked for this on Youtube but nothing is close or related to my question.
Please help.

Comment: You want a button to click and then START PBi app on its way?

Comment: Yes, basically when the person clicks the button, it immediatly opens a specific file on Power BI

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes , I'm sorry, I'm new to posting questions and still learning to do so correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved,
Thanks to @AleXcel,
Here's the command

```
Sub cmdOpen_Click()
VBA.Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI 
Desktop\bin\PBiDesktop.exe [C:\Users\nizar\Downloads\power 
bi\HelloWorld.pbix]"
End Sub
```

The only difference between @AleXcel 's code is that the [ ] are necessary to open it.

Answer (score 0):

Please test this code, adapting the paths and file name:

```
Private Sub cmdOpen_Click()

    VBA.Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBiDesktop.exe c:\pathToYourFile.pbix"

End Sub
```

You can improve this code passing the pbix filename as a variable.

Comment: I tried this but it says the file doesn't exist, is it because of the path ?
`Sub cmdOpen_Click()
VBA.Shell "C:\Users\nizar\Downloads\power bi\HelloWorld"
End Sub`

Comment: is there any prob with the path, like do i have to keep a few things like

Comment: Now I tried this
`VBA.Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBiDesktop.exe [C:\Users\nizar\Downloads\power bi\HelloWorld.pbix]"`
And it shows me a small box with `Syntax: PBIDesktop.exe [filename.pbix]

Comment: 1) Check if PowerBi is installed and in wich directory. Mine is at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBiDesktop.exe. 2) Check the correct path to the .pbix file. Say, C:\Users\nizar\Downloads\power bi\HelloWorld.pbix (is this really your pbix file?) Note that the extension .pbix compounds the filename... To test it you may create one test file in PowerBi, save it in a folder and then put its complete path and filename on the command line:
VBA.Shell "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Power BI Desktop\bin\PBiDesktop.exe c:\pathToYourFile.pbix" Note the space beetwen the two paths, OK?

Comment: Hiii AleXcel,
IT WORKED, I tried a test file on my desktop and it worked, now I will try with a file in a foler, but essentially it worked.
Thanks a lot. You nailed it.